# HTML preserve header when loading another page

Tags: html, caching, header

I am building a website and when I click on one of my header's page links, it loads the whole page again, rather than preserving the header and only loading the main content. For example:
When you click on a button on the sidebar of YouTube, it will, for example, load the watch later playlist, and preserve the search bar and sidebar. How would I go about doing this on my website?

Comment: What have you looked at? Have you looked at using aJax?

Comment: After looking at aJax I apologise for me being so unaware of it. I feel slightly stupid now that I've looked at it so thank you for pointing me in the right direction and sorry for my slight stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using aJax. This should resolve your issue.